# How to run Javascript file in pdf

Tags: pdf, cad, solidworks

We have a PDF 3d CAD file exported from solidworks. In this file we want to run a javascript file. How embed a javascript file in PDF. What are the tools available.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." The canonical tool however (which Google should have pointed out) is **Acrobat Pro**.

Comment: [HOOPS Publish](http://www.techsoft3d.com/our-products/hoops-publish) may also help you with this

Comment: @ Jongware yes. Adobe Acrobat pro has the facility to add, edit and embed javascript fles or codes to PDF